# Como realizar um "merge commit" ou "merge pull request" no "Github"?

Tags: git, github

Quero contribuir para um projeto no github só que eu não quero postar um PR com 28 commits.
Como faço (no Github) para juntar esses commits?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No GitHub não é necessário ter essa preocupação, pois o owner do projeto pode decidir o que fazer com o seu PR. Serão apresentadas 3 possibilidades:

1. "Create a merge commit" (todos os commits entram na branch)
2. "Squash and merge" (todos os commits da tua branch serão combinados em um único commit)
3. "Rebase and merge" (o rebase é feito antes do merge)

Independentemente deste recurso acima, você também pode fazer o *squash* manualmente. O mais fácil seria usar uma GUI, caso não seja familiarizado com os comandos do git.

Caso queira fazer via linha de comando, uma possibilidade é usar o `rebase`, fazendo

`git rebase -i HEAD~[quantidade de commits]`

ou

`git rebase -i [SHA do commit inicial]`.

Caso já tenha feito o push desta branch, será necessário fazer um push com a flag `force`, algo como `git push origin SuaBranch --force`.

Há algumas outras alternativas para atingir esse mesmo resultado, como fazer um `git reset` e um novo commit, por exemplo.

Answer (score 4):

Existem [diferentes formas](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) de fazer isto. Não tem como fazer isto direto no GitHub, você vai precisar fazer isto localmente e depois subir para o GitHub as alterações.

A minha preferida é usar o comando `rebase` para isto e marcando os commits que serão unidos com `squash`.

Partindo do ponto que você tem 28 commits, o comando ficaria:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~28
```

Quando executar este comando, o `git` vai abrir um editor de texto para escolher como este `rebase` será feito, apresentando uma mensagem contendo todas as mensagens dos 28 commits. [Algo assim](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History):

```
pick f7f3f6d changed my name a bit
pick 310154e updated README formatting and added blame
pick a5f4a0d added cat-file
```

Mantenha um dos commits com `pick` e o restante mude para `squash`:

```
pick f7f3f6d changed my name a bit
squash 310154e updated README formatting and added blame
squash a5f4a0d added cat-file
```

Salve o arquivo e saia. O Git irá aplicar estas mudanças e irá abrir novamente o editor de texto para escolher a mensagem do commit:

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# The first commit's message is:
changed my name a bit

# This is the 2nd commit message:

updated README formatting and added blame

# This is the 3rd commit message:

added cat-file
```

Eu particularmente gosto de deixar todas as mensagens (se não forem muitas), para ter o rastreamento do que foi feito com detalhes. Outra opção é comentar tudo com `#` e criar uma única mensagem, mais bem formatada e completa, englobando todas as alterações feitas.

Depois disto, você pode fazer o `git push` para sua branch. Se você já havia feito um push com os 28 commits, será preciso usar a opção *force* para reescrever o histórico na branch remota:

```
git push -f
```

E fique atento de um possível problema: **não use esta dica** do `rebase` e união de commits caso alguém tenha criado uma branch a partir desta sua.